# Why is this url not being resolved by reverse on Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a method that updates an entry:

```
@require_POST
def update(request, uuid):
    posti = get_object_or_404(Post, uuid=uuid)
    f = PostForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        posti.title = request.POST['title']
        posti.text = request.POST['text']
        posti.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(django.urls.reverse('posti:detail', args=(posti.uuid,)))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "No title in form")
        return render(request, 'posti/detail.html', {'form': f})
```

I'm trying to test this method with a case:

```
def create_post():
    """

    :rtype : Post
    """
    data = {'title': 'Esto es un titulo', 'text': 'Esto es un texto de prueba'}
    post = Post.create_post(data['title'], data['text'])
    post.save()
    print('The UUID is: ', post.uuid)
    return post

def test_updating_post_with_no_title(self):
        """
        A post with no title should not be saved
        :return:
        """
        p = create_post()
        print('(test) The UUID is: ', p.uuid)
        data = {'title': '', 'text': 'Esto es un texto de prueba'}
        url = reverse('posti:update', args=(p.uuid,))
        response = self.client.post(url, data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No title in form")
```

Whatever I do I always get this error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update' with
>   arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['posti/update/(?P[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/$']

The UUID does show up in the test using `print(p.uuid)` in both methods but it's not reaching the fourth line from bottom to top. Where it says "with arguments '('',)' not found" an UUID should show up. Why is it not displaying it?

EDIT: UUID is a SmallUUID. I don't know if that's problematic.

Comment: Because "+" matches *one or more*.

Comment: Care to explain? I don't understand. I use the same regex for another page and it does work

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: The problem is that the argument is not showing up when it runs the update. So it's as though it's evaluating an empty value. What I need to figure out is why the value is not showing.